# Can we prove that $t$ must be a Mersenne prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

This question

[Equations involving arithmetic functions, totatives and even perfect numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2745815/equations-involving-arithmetic-functions-totatives-and-even-perfect-numbers?noredirect=1#comment5665681_2745815)

can be answered positive if the following can be proven.

Let $t\ge 1$ be an integer and denote $$s:=\sigma\left(\frac{t(t+1)}{2}\right)$$ $$p:=\varphi\left(\frac{t(t+1)}{2}\right)$$

$\sigma(n)$ is the divisor-sum-function and $\varphi(n)$ the totient-function.

> Claim :
>
> - If $s=4p+t+1$ holds, then $t$ is a Mersenne-prime.
> - If $t^2-1=4p$ holds, then $t$ is a Mersenne-prime.

The claim is true for $t\le 10^6$

Comment: I think I can prove that $t$ is Mersenne prime if both $s=4p+t+1$ and $t^2-1=4p$ hold. Judging by the other question you quoted, there is an "and" in between. Is this what you are after?

Comment: This is a useful partial result , but I think the formulation clearly indicates that I search a proof of each implication. Perhaps, $t^2-1=4p\implies t$ is Mersenne-prime is easier to show.

Comment: Probably. Technically, propositions 1 to 3 use only $t^2-1=4p$ ... work in progress ... the only scaring factor is Wikipedia mentioning "It is unknown whether there is any odd perfect number ..."

Answer (score 4):

**If both**
$$t^2-1=4p \tag{1}$$
$$s=4p+t+1 \tag{2}$$

hold. We can deduce:

---

**Proposition 1.** $t$-odd.

Easy to see from $(1) \Rightarrow t^2=4p+1$.

---

**Proposition 2.** If $t=2k+1$ then
$$k(k+1)=\varphi(2k+1)\varphi(k+1)=p$$

Given $\gcd(t,t+1)=1$ and [$\varphi(n)$ is multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#The_function_is_multiplicative), which means
$$p=\varphi\left(\frac{t(t+1)}{2}\right)=\varphi\left(t\right)\varphi\left(\frac{t+1}{2}\right)$$
then $(1)$ becomes
$$t^2=4\varphi\left(t\right)\varphi\left(\frac{t+1}{2}\right)+1 \tag{3}$$
Substituting 
$$k(k+1)=\varphi(2k+1)\varphi(k+1)$$

---

**Proposition 3.** $t$-[is square free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer)

If $q$-prime has the property that $q^2 \mid t \Rightarrow q \mid \varphi(t)$. But then, from $(3) \Rightarrow q \mid 1$ - contradiction.

---

**Proposition 4.** $\frac{t(t+1)}{2}$ is a [perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number).

I.e. $t+1=s-4p$
and
$$(t-1)(t+1)=4p \iff (t-1)(s-4p)=4p \iff t(s-4p)-s+4p=4p \iff \\
t=\frac{s}{s-4p}$$
But $t$-is odd (*propositions 1 and 2*)
$$2k+1=\frac{s}{s-4k(k+1)} \iff 
2k=\frac{4k(k+1)}{s-4k(k+1)} \iff \\
s-4k(k+1)=2(k+1) \iff s=4k(k+1)+2(k+1)=2(k+1)(2k+1)$$
or
$$s=\sigma\left(\frac{t(t+1)}{2}\right)=2\cdot\frac{t(t+1)}{2}$$

---

**Proposition 5.** $t$ is a Mersenne prime.

From *Proposition 1 and 3* $t$ is odd and square free, i.e. its prime factorisation is $t=q_1\cdot q_2\cdot ...\cdot q_r, q_i>2, q_i\ne q_j, i\ne j$. [$\sigma(n)$ is multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Properties) and $\gcd(t,t+1)=1$ thus
$$\sigma\left(\frac{t(t+1)}{2}\right)=\sigma(t)\sigma\left(\frac{t+1}{2}\right)=
\sigma\left(\frac{t+1}{2}\right)\prod\limits_{i=1}^r(q_i+1)=2^r\cdot Q$$

- if $r\geq 2$, from $(2)$, $4 \mid (t+1)$ and (from *proposition 4*) $\frac{t(t+1)}{2}$ is even perfect number, [thus $t$ is Mersenne prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Even_perfect_numbers).
- if $r=1$, then $t$-is prime and $\varphi(t)=t-1=2k$ and from *proposition 2* 
  $$k(k+1)=\varphi(2k+1)\varphi(k+1)=2k\varphi(k+1) \Rightarrow 2\mid k+1=\frac{t+1}{2}$$
  and (from *proposition 4*) $\frac{t(t+1)}{2}$ is even perfect number, [thus $t$ is Mersenne prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Even_perfect_numbers).

---

Done. It might be more difficult (if possible at all) to deduct this from individual $(1)$ or $(2)$.

**Remark**: [This book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/104-Number-Theory-Problems-Training/dp/0817645276), page 72, has a short proof of

> **Theorem 1.51.** An even positive integer $n$ is perfect if and only if
>   $n = 2^{k−1}M_k$ for some positive integer $k$ for which $M_k$
>   (Mersenne number) is a prime.